# SwiftUI - How to load in image from a URL that will comes from an @ObservedObject

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, observable

In my case, I'm calling an API that will return an image URL, and only then can I make a second network request to fetch the image data and set it in my UI. This will crash because image doesn't exist yet

```
@ObservedObject var imageNetworkManager = ImageNetworkManager()

var body: some View {
    ...
    RemoteImage(url: imageNetworkManager.image) // This will crash because image doesn't exist yet
    ...
}
```

Here is a RemoteImage class I found from [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/loading-images/3292)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct RemoteImage: View {

    private enum LoadState {
        case loading, success, failure
    }

    private class Loader: ObservableObject {
        var data = Data()
        var state = LoadState.loading

        init(url: String) {
            guard let parsedURL = URL(string: url) else {
                fatalError("Invalid URL: \(url)")
            }

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: parsedURL) { data, response, error in
                if let data = data, data.count > 0 {
                    self.data = data
                    self.state = .success
                } else {
                    self.state = .failure
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.objectWillChange.send()
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }

    @StateObject private var loader: Loader
    var loading: Image
    var failure: Image

    var body: some View {
        selectImage()
            .resizable()
    }

    init(url: String, loading: Image = Image(systemName: "photo"), failure: Image = Image(systemName: "multiply.circle")) {
        _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: Loader(url: url))
        self.loading = loading
        self.failure = failure
    }

    private func selectImage() -> Image {
        switch loader.state {
        case .loading:
            return loading
        case .failure:
            return failure
        default:
            if let image = UIImage(data: loader.data) {
                return Image(uiImage: image)
            } else {
                return failure
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since the URL hasn't loaded yet, this wil cause a crash. Does anyone have a solution to this?
Thanks

Comment: If `image` is optional, you can do `if let imageUrl = imageNetworkManager.image { RemoteImage(url: imageUrl) }`. Make sure that `image` is a `@Published` property

Comment: @NewDev Indeed this does prevent the crash, and loads the image. The only problem I see is that I would need to have this imageview showing onAppear because it has a placeholder. With this solution, the imageview doesn't exist at first so it can't show the placeholder image. I can probably have an if let else to show a second imageview as a placeholder, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: You can change `RemoteImage` to accept an optional url as a parameter and deal with the `nil` case there. I mean, *somewhere* you have to wait for the URL; where depends on what your own criteria